# Proof of fundamental lemma of Riemannian geometry in the 1-form connection formalism

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, tensors, differential-forms, fiber-bundles

I'm trying to understand the proof of this version of the fundamental lemma of Riemannian geometry.

Let $\pi : \mathcal{F}_{on}(M) \rightarrow M $ the orthonormal frame bundle of an n-dimensional Riemannian manifold $M$ and let $\eta$ ∈ $\Omega^1(\mathcal{F}_{on}(M), \mathbb{R}^n )$ be
the tautological form. Then there exists a unique $\mathfrak{so}(V)$-valued 1-form $\theta \in \Omega^1(\mathcal{F}_{on}(M), \mathbb{R}^n )$ such that
$$
d\eta= \theta \wedge \eta
$$
or equivalently, if we call $\theta= (e_i \otimes \eta^j) \otimes \eta^i_J$ where $e_i$ is the dual of $\eta^i$ we have
$$
d \eta^i=\eta^i_j \wedge \eta^j
$$
$$
\eta^i_j+\eta^j_i=0
$$
The proof is the following:

On $M$, let $\bar{\eta}$ be an orthonormal coframe, giving a local trivialization
of $\mathcal{F}_{on}(M)$ such that $\eta = g^{−1}\pi^∗\bar{\eta}$ for some $O(\mathbb{R^n})$-valued function $g$ on the
frame bundle. Then
$$
 d\eta = −g^{−1}dg ∧ η + g^{−1}\pi^∗d\bar{\eta}.
$$
So, there exist 1-forms $\alpha^i_{j}$ on the frame bundle such that
$d\eta^i=\alpha^i_j \wedge \eta^j$ [...]

(source : [Cartan for beginners, second edition](https://bookstore.ams.org/view?ProductCode=GSM/175) lemma 3.1.4 )

i don't understand why this statement is true. How is the term $g^{−1}\pi^∗d\bar{\eta}$ handled?

Edit

As suggested by Ted Shifrin in the comments i looked up to [a comprehensive introduction to differential geometry](https://books.google.com/books/about/A_Comprehensive_Introduction_to_Differen.html?id=jVPvAAAAMAAJ) and i found It a more "beginners friendly" book

Comment: What is your source for this?

Comment: @Deane [Cartan for beginners](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-61) lemma 3.1.4

Comment: It must be the [2016 edition](https://bookstore.ams.org/view?ProductCode=GSM/175). In the 2003 edition that I bought recently it is Lemma 2.6.5 and the proof is a bit different.

Comment: @KurtG. you are right, i quoted the wrong edition in the comment. Any idea about why this is true? because i think it is widely  assumed also in the exercises.

Comment: I am not quite sure if you ask about Ivey & Landsberg 2003 Lemma 2.6.5 or 2016 Lemma 3.1.4 which seems to have given a slightly different proof. In case you are asking about moving frames in general: $d\eta^i=\eta^i_j\wedge \eta^j$ is Cartan's first structure equation. You can see it in action [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2044724/maurer-cartan-form-and-curvature-form-on-a-lie-group/2045252#2045252). [This page](https://www.akalin.com/curvature-moving-frames) is also highly recommended.

Comment: @KurtG. thank you for the links, my doubt was about why it looks like the term $g^{-1}\pi^* d\bar{\eta}=\gamma^i_j \wedge g^{-1}\pi^*(\bar{\eta})$, for some one form $\gamma^i_j$. I think it has something to do with the trivialization of $\mathcal{F}_{on}(M)$, but i can't figure out why does it holds. The book seems to define the 1-connection form without assuming that there is an affine connection, but only using the tautological form of $\mathcal{F}_{on}(M)$

Comment: That's definitely not the notation they use in my older edition of the book so I cannot comment. Much of the bundle stuff I still need to practice.

Comment: So, working downstairs on $M$, what is $d\tilde\eta$? We’re then going to pull back by $\pi$.

Comment: @TedShifrin $d \bar{\eta}=f_{ij} \bar{\eta}^i \wedge \bar{\eta}^j$ for some function. When i pull back i should obtain $\pi^*(f_{ij}\bar{\eta}^i) \wedge \eta^j$. Is it correct?

Comment: Correct except for missing $g$.

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you very much. I was overcomplicating things

Comment: You might find the exposition in volume 2 of Spivak a bit more explicit on this stuff. Although I know the authors of the book you’re working on, I do not know the book. You might also look at Jeanne Clelland’s new book on moving frames.